# Nextjs issue with Server-Side Rendering

Tags: typescript, next.js, middleware, router

After a period of time, I've encountered an issue with server-side rendering (SSR) on my website. When attempting to access the website, it appears that SSR is not being triggered.

My middleware:

```
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/userOverview",
    "/documents/:path*",
    "/nonusresident",
    "/strategy/:path*",
    "/portfolio",
    "/userDetails",
    "/advisorDetails"
  ]
};

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const response = NextResponse.next();
  const isFirebaseAuthCookies: boolean = req.cookies.has("firebase-auth");
  if (!isFirebaseAuthCookies && req.nextUrl.pathname !== "/") {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", req.url));
  }
  return response;
}
```

Upon further investigation, it appears that server-side rendering (SSR) is only triggered when refreshing the browser.

Upon removing the middleware, SSR functions as expected.